# Spawning new task from another task

Tags: freertos, esp32

I am experimenting with esp32 and freertos. I want to create a new task `t2` from another task `t1`. In `t2`, I am printing statement in `for` loop but `for` loop stops printing after first print and ESP32 module gets stuck after first print only. Following is the code I am using:

```
void t2(void *pvParam){
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"task 2 started \n");
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        print("...task 2 printing\n");
}

void t1(void)
{
    BaseType_t xReturned;
    TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;
    xReturned = xTaskCreate(&t2,"t2",4048,NULL,configMAX_PRIORITIES-1,&xHandle);
    printf("xReturned = %d \n", xReturned);
    if(xReturned == pdPASS)
    {
         vTaskDelete( xHandle );
    }
}   
void app_main()
{   
    xTaskCreate(&t1,"namet",4048,NULL,configMAX_PRIORITIES- 1,NULL);
}
```

What can be the reason for above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tasks have no infinite loop. They just run to completion. They do the job 1 time, then nothing more.

I do not understand your purpose, but if you just want to experiment (this is not a proper solution), you can have an infinite loop in t1 and create t2 with a **higher priority** (so that t1 won't interfere and call `xTaskCreate()` again before t2 completes), leave t2 code as it is. That should make it "keep printing".

```
void t1(void)
{
 while (1)
 {
    BaseType_t xReturned;
    TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;
    xReturned = xTaskCreate(&t2,"t2",4048,NULL,configMAX_PRIORITIES,&xHandle);
    printf("xReturned = %d \n", xReturned);
    if(xReturned == pdPASS)
    {
         vTaskDelete( xHandle );
    }
 }
}
```

You need to define clearly your goal in order to come up with a good design. You have to take into account scheduling policy (preemptive, cooperative), task priorities, activation, etc.